# How do I access single JSON API item? (Python 3.6)

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

I am trying to access the values from an API json item called DataClasses that looks like this.

"DataClasses":["Dates of birth","Email addresses","IP addresses","Passwords","Usernames","Website activity"]

With this code:

```
import requests
import json

with open('dataclasstest.txt', 'r') as f:
    emails = [line.strip() for line in f]

print("Email" + ":" + "Data Classes")

def main():
for name in emails:
    url = 'https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v2/breachedaccount/' + name
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'dataclass.py'
        'Accept: application/vnd.haveibeenpwned.v2+json'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    content = r.json()
    data = json.loads(content)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        for item in data:
            print(unicode(item['DataClasses']))
            time.sleep(2)
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        print("No Data")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

Can anyone help me get on the right track? I've been looking online for weeks and still can't figure it out. I've found similar answers on here but when I try them it still doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it. I will post only the relevant lines of code:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(json.loads(r.content)[0].get('DataClasses'))
```

After reading the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) for `requests` the code above can be rewritten more simpler.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.json()[0].get('DataClasses'))
```

Because we know that the response represents JSON data, `requests` has a built-in JSON decoder. `r.json()` returns a list of objects, or a list of `dict`. We then extract the first element with `r.json()[0]`. The `.get` method is exactly the same as calling `r.json()[0]['DataClasses']`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: This worked great. Can you explain how this works? I am new to Python